# How do I change the transfer method on Windows Easy Transfer?

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-easy-transfer

The first time I started up Windows Easy Transfer on my new Windows 8.1. machine, it asked me which transfer method I wanted to use. I mistakenly chose usb-drive. Realising this, I quit and restarted Windows Easy Transfer, but now it doesn't ask me which transfer method I want, and assumes I want to transfer with a file, not the network, as I now wish to.

Restarting the PC didn't do the trick.

How can I change this option?

Answer (score 0):

When you open Easy Transfer, there should be a back button in the upper lefthand corner. If you click it you should be able to select network.

Comment: No, I tried that before. It doesn't bring me back there, it's greyed out.